# Why does Archive fail if there is code for SwiftUI Previews in the Preview Content folder?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In my SwiftUI app, I have put some sample model objects in Xcode's "Preview Content" folder. I only access them in my SwiftUI `PreviewProvider`s. My understanding is that the code/assets in this folder are only used for previewing in the Canvas. My previews work properly. I'm using Xcode 11.6 (11E708).

However, when I go to Archive my app, it fails because it cannot find these sample model objects. I was under the impression that `PreviewProvider` code is not build into the final binary as of Xcode 11. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485562/are-the-if-debug-statements-really-needed-for-previews-in-swiftui-to-remove-it), along with the item from the Xcode 11 release notes that says,

> **Resolved Issues**
>
> The `#if`/`#endif` compiler conditionals surrounding PreviewProvider types have been removed from SwiftUI templates. PreviewProviders aren’t properly removed from built products when archived. (51539802)

(Curiously, I am able to compile with the Release configuration. It's just Archive that fails.)

As a workaround, I can put the `#if DEBUG`/`#endif` wrappers around my `PreviewProvider` but the above quote from the release notes indicates that shouldn't be necessary.

Do I misunderstand how the "Preview Content" folder works?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted this down.. I think this is a great question. I've also run into this and used the same workaround `#if DEBUG`. I hope someone can shed light on this!

Comment: Same issue. I have a custom class in "Preview Content" folder which causes a compiler error when I try to archive. I'll have to add the `#if DEBUG` until Apple resolves the issue. (Xcode 12.2).

Comment: SwiftUI previews can only be deployed to devices when the deployment target of the project is iOS 10+ - does your deployment target support < iOS 10?

Comment: @PranavKasetti it works when wrapped in `#if DEBUG` so it’s not a deployment target issue

Comment: @LaX that's not correct, archiving includes compiling and deploying to a generic device target. I've taken the known issue from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes). When < iOS 10, the `#if DEBUG` looks needed since they are not stripped on deploy.

Comment: @PranavKasetti - My project is targeting iOS 14+.

Comment: Ok, that narrows it down at least. Do you have any custom classes in `Preview Content`? Also maybe worth filing a bug report on Feedback Assistant.app.

Comment: Yes I did have custom classes, for my sample test data. Yeah, given the number of upvotes and lack of answers I don't think I'm missing anything now. Probably worth a feedback.

Comment: I filed FB8969539 for this with Apple. Here is the writeup, if anyone else wants to clone: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4985741033603072

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Nevermind, this approach "works" but the preview code is still in the final archive, so it doesn't really help anything.

<strike>I put all my preview test data in its own `PreviewProvider` so that I can access it in other Previews. The Archive still succeeds, and the test data will get stripped in the final Archive. No `#if DEBUG` is needed.</strike>

Example (specific to my own use case):

```swift
struct PreviewData: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text("This is test data for use in other previews.")
    }

    // Use enums for namespacing if desired
    enum Choices {
        static let deals = Choice(id: UUID().uuidString, text: "I want the best deals.", iconName: "bestDealsIcon")
        static let technology = Choice(id: UUID().uuidString, text: "I love technology!", iconName: "technologyIcon")
    }
```

Then I can access `PreviewData.Choices.deals` in other `PreviewProvider`s.

Comment: somehow this solution doesn't work for me. I'm still getting the not found compiler error. So I had to use `#if DEBUG` as well. I'm using Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33).

Comment: Nevermind - I realized this test data is *not* stripped from the final archive. I tried using some of it in my normal views (not Previews) and it works, when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue occur, only I was building an **App Clip** for an existing app. I couldn't compile with the release scheme or archive for distribution with neither versions of Xcode 12.5.1 or 13.0.

The solution was to include the `Preview Content` directory under the development assets of the parent app's target, **not** the App Clip target itself. As a result, I got it to work in all scenarios, including **SwiftUI** previews, release builds and archiving the parent app for distribution.